# Using selenium webdriver to find the label text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was having a hard time using Selenium web driver to find the label text for the below scenario.

```
<tr id="row"> 
<td width="148" height="22" align="left"> 
<b> Label Text</b> 
</td> </tr>
```

How do I get the Label Text using webdriver ?

Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for the reply. I think I should have been more specific. I have a list of td tags inside the tr tag.
For eg:

```
<tr id="row"> 
<td width="148" height="22" align="left"> 
<b> Label Text 1</b> 
<td width="148" height="22" align="left"> 
<b> Label Text 2</b> 

<td width="148" height="22" align="left"> 
<b> Label Text 3</b> 
</td> </tr>
```

driver.findElement(By.id("row")).getText() would retrieve me all of those label values. Can I get the label value based on the location in the page ? Thanks.

Comment: you have already asked your question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095195/finding-label-text-when-id-does-not-exist?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("row")).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all required labels one by one by using the following code -

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='row']/td/b"));

for(int i=0;i<list.size;i++){

   list.get(i).getText();

  }
```

I hope that this answers your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get a value via its location you can use something like:

```
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> cells = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//tr[@id='row']//td"));
    foreach(IWebElement cell in cells)
    {
        if (cell.Location.X == targetX && cell.Location.Y == targetY)
        {
            cell.Text;
        } 
    }
```

Also, FindElement will only return the first element found that matches the criteria, FindElements must be used to store all matches.