# Finding label text when id does not exist

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the selenium web driver to find the label text in the below html tags:

```
<tr id="row" style="display: inline; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
<td>
<table width="776" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="92" height="25" align="left">**Label Text&nbsp**;</td>
<td width="227">
<td width="170" align="left">">**Label Text 2&nbsp**;</td>
</td>
</tr>
```

I used driver.findElement(By.id("row")).getText(), but it retrieves me nothing.
How do I get it to print Label Text.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To access the 'Label Text' cells, you will need to search for the cells themselves and *not* the row that contains them. If you were using WatiN this would be the case.
An alternative way of finding any element with 'Label Text' would be:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> temp = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@text='Label Text']));
```

If 'Label Text' in your example is a place holder for different text this will become tricky and you could just attempt to grab each cell within the tableRow containing the cells. However, only the first row appears to have an id. Hope this helps!

EDIT:
Alternatively, a (very) hacky solution if you know exactly which cell you want and it has a unique size (like your example) you could try finding all cells and then search through their widths manually. Eg:
    foreach(IWebElement temp in tempCells)
    {
        if(temp.Size.Width == 170)
            temp.Text;
    }

Comment: Just fyi - You are missing closing parantheses in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).GetAttribute("text")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `getText`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
List<WebElement> list;
list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("id('row')//td[string-length(text()) > 1]"));
```

That should get a `List` of `<td>` elements which have a text node longer than 1 char (change to 5 if `&nbsp;` actually counts for 5 =) ).

or maybe

```
list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("id('row')//td[@align='left']"));
```

if all the elements you want to get really have in common the `align = 'left'` part which can be seen in your example.