# Getting the text after a label with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I've found other questions that look for [label text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081536/using-selenium-webdriver-to-find-the-label-text), but what I'm after is the text after a label.

So for example, I have a section of code:

```
<p>
<label>My awesome name:</label>
"Mark Mayo"
</p>
```

My understanding is that if I wanted the label, I could use an XPath query with something like:

```
//label[text()='My awesome name:']
```

to see if the label exists, but am unsure how to access plain text that isn't inside the label, but after it instead.

Suggestions?

Comment: Good question. Have you tried getting `<p>`'s text?

Comment: @Nashibukasan I figured that might work, but there are going to be more labels within the <p>, and so it'd only be a short  term solution. Experimenting with that at the moment.

Comment: I have a feeling that if there were more labels and subsequent text, that getting text from `<p>` would get you all the text under `<p>` not contained by label tags. Perhaps trying some css `>` next element selectors?

Comment: Getting <p>'s text just gets me the label text + the other text.  I eventually settled for confirming that it's part of that content, but it's not ideal :/

Comment: You can perhaps get the `innerHTML` and then do a regex match.

Answer (score 1):

Something like (I use Java syntax)

```
public String getNodeTextContent(WebElement node) {
    String nodeContent = node.getAttribute("textContent");

    List<WebElement> childs = node.findElements(By.xpath("*"));
    if (childs.size() == 0) {
        return allContent;
    }

    for (WebElement child : childs) {
        nodeContent = nodeContent.replace(child.getAttribute("textContent"), "");
    }

    return nodeContent;
}
```

it basically just removes the text contents of all direct children of the node from the node contents, which should leave only the real contents of the node.